# Why is the semaphore being fetched and not created?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, semaphore

I am trying to get the hang of semaphores. I have written a program which deals with semaphores and in which I have this function to create a single semaphore :

```
int semcreate()
{
    semp = semget(ftok("./output.txt", 'a'),1,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0664);

    if(semp == -1) /*Semaphore exists, fetch*/
    {
        printf("Semaphore fetched\n");
        semp = semget(ftok("./output.txt", 'a'), 1, 0);
    }
    else if(semp>=0) /*Semaphore created here*/
    {
        printf("Semaphore created\n");
        seminit(); /* Initialize semaphore*/
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I run this program from two separate terminals, both of the instances print `Semaphore fetched`. Is this the correct behaviour? Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the semaphore exists on the system. Use command `ipcs` to list all the semaphore in the system and remove the semaphore created by your program using `ipcrm`.